# How to show streamgaph axes correctly in R-shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, stream-graph

I was using streamgraph. It was working fine on standalone program, however, it was not working as expected on r-shiny. On R-shiny, the X-Axis just disappeared. Please see the figures attached. Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you.

Code to generate the case,

> library(dplyr) 
>   library(streamgraph) 
>   library(ggplot2movies)
>
> movies %>%
>   select(year, Action, Animation, Comedy, Drama, Documentary, Romance, Short) %>%
>   tidyr::gather(genre, value, -year)
>   %>%   group_by(year, genre) %>%   tally(wt=value) %>%   ungroup %>%
>   streamgraph("genre", "n", "year") %>%   sg_axis_x(20) %>%
>   sg_fill_brewer("PuOr") %>%
>   sg_legend(show=TRUE, label="Genres: ")

Figure 1 (with visitble  X - Axis )
[image]

Figure 2 (On R-shiny, X - Axis is not visible )
[image]

Comment: (i've been a bit behind on issues for streamgraph but if you haven't filed an issue, please do with a reprex and I'll see if i can triage+tweak)